# save all file in window objects praat

Tags: praat

I have some files. wav in the object window, how can I save them automatically?

I found this script  but I get an error:

```
directoryName$ = chooseDirectory$: "Choose a directory to save all the new files in"
if directoryName$ <> ""
    for i to numberOfSelectedSounds
       selectObject: sound [i]
       Save as WAV file: directoryName$ + "/sound" + string$ (i) + ".wav"
    endfor
endif
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about programming, not linguistics.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to debug this code, but found a neater version here, that definitely works for wav files:
https://phon.chass.ncsu.edu/manual/save_selected.praat
Remember to specify the correct destination path. Or substitute the following lines:

```
 #PROMPT THE USER FOR INPUT
form Please select objects and choose a path
     sentence path /home/jeff/wheremyfilesare
endform
```

with:

```
  path$ = chooseDirectory$: "Choose a directory to save all the new files in”
```

to activate the GUI.